# How to get a specific paragraph to float left, and the image to float right

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I'm doing a personal project and am having troubles getting images to float right of some text.

I'd like the **single** paragraph to float left, and the image to float right and **not** have any following paragraphs underneath to be beside the image as well. I **only** want that single paragraph beside the image. I always want a little bit of space in between the image and the text.

The site is [here](http://norex.incredifull.com/) and the image is on the "past" page.

On the "past" page, the image should float right of the **first** paragraph.

Past page HTML:
    
    
    
    Past

```
<div class="bl-content">
<h2>When I was young...</h2>
<p>I wanted to be a <span>crazy cat lady.</span> I then realized that being a crazy cat lady doesn't give me an income but infact, did quite the opposite and took away any money I would have.</p>
<img src="/images/catparty.jpg" style="float:right">
<p>So I chose the next best thing &#8210; Web Development and Web Design. I knew it was <i>"my thing"</i> since Grade 6 when I found a drag and drop website maker called Piczo. It was all of the rage when I was 12 years old, I assure you. It wasn't appealing and definitely wasn't user-friendly... but it was mine and I loved it.</p>
<p>I decided to challenge myself more and learn some basic HTML and CSS so that I could get more involved in my new found passion. This lead me to have my own site on Freewebs.</p>
<p>Not too long after having my first Freewebs site I recieved my own subdomain. After that, I recieved my own <i>adoptable</i> domain. I was still young at the time so the best domain name I chose was something along the lines of <span>broken-wings</span> dot something.</p>
<p>On all of the sites that I owned, I would create content for other users with my <strong>amazing</strong> version of Paint Shop Pro (well... it was to me!) which included backgrounds, wallpapers, HTML and CSS tricks, and a lot of other things that I believed were great. I may have not of been the best, but it sure gave me an amazing foundation for school.</p>

</div>
<span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
</section>
```

Some CSS:

```
/* Custom content */

.bl-content p {
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-size: 1.7em;
line-height: 1.8;
}

.bl-content p.norex {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bl-content p span {
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #ed1556;
}
```

If I'm not giving enough HTML or CSS I do apologize. You can go to the link provided, but I feel like it's an easy fix. There's a lot of CSS and HTML in this layout and it's difficult to pinpoint what exactly needs to be shown.

Comment: have you tryied adding the image inside the paragraph?

Comment: @Ibu Just did. Not much of a difference, though.

Comment: when you move the image inside the paragraph, move it to the beginning of the paragraph instead of the end.

Comment: @andi Thanks so much! I knew it was a simple fix, didn't think it was that simple... duhhhhhhh :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
<div class="bl-content">
<h2>When I was young...</h2>
<img src="/images/catparty.jpg" style="float:right">
<p>I wanted to be a <span>crazy cat lady.</span> I then realized that being a crazy cat lady doesn't give me an income but infact, did quite the opposite and took away any money I would have.</p>

<p>So I chose the next best thing &#8210; Web Development and Web Design. I knew it was    <i>"my thing"</i> since Grade 6 when I found a drag and drop website maker called Piczo. It was all of the rage when I was 12 years old, I assure you. It wasn't appealing and definitely wasn't user-friendly... but it was mine and I loved it.</p>
<p>I decided to challenge myself more and learn some basic HTML and CSS so that I could get more involved in my new found passion. This lead me to have my own site on Freewebs.</p>
<p>Not too long after having my first Freewebs site I recieved my own subdomain. After that, I recieved my own <i>adoptable</i> domain. I was still young at the time so the best domain name I chose was something along the lines of <span>broken-wings</span> dot something.</p>
<p>On all of the sites that I owned, I would create content for other users with my        
<strong>amazing</strong> version of Paint Shop Pro (well... it was to me!) which   included backgrounds, wallpapers, HTML and CSS tricks, and a lot of other things that I believed were great. I may have not of been the best, but it sure gave me an amazing foundation for school.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats are technically still an "in-flow" element. This means that by default floats will clear previous elements if they cannot fit beside them. The problem you are having is that the image is after the first paragraph. Since the paragraph is full width, it shows up beneath it. Move the image above the paragraph and the image will take width precedence and the paragraph will wrap around it.

You may also need to clear the paragraph directly after the first paragraph since you only want the one paragraph to be next to the picture. Simply clear in the same direction as the float.